# Why I can't view my UDP received Image in Android Studio?

Tags: java, c#, android, imageview, udp

I succeeded in sending a `string` **from** *Android Studio Java UDP Client* **to** *Visual Studio C# UDP Server*, and a response back from the Server to the Client.

Now I am trying to send an `Image` back from the server instead of a `string` response. So on client button click, I am supposed to get an Image back from the server. No syntax errors and no weird behavior. It's just nothing happens and I can't seem to see the received image on my ImageView and when I step over it my `final Bitmap ReceivedImage` is `null`

Do I need to convert into something other than `Bitmap`? Is this the right way? Maybe something else.. Can anyone help me point out my mistake? Thanks

**C# Server:**

```
    class UdpServer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] dataReceived = new byte[1024];
        UdpClient serverSocket = new UdpClient(15000);

        string path = "C:\\Users\\kkhalaf\\Desktop\\Capture.PNG"; // image path
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // prepare
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs); // prepare
        byte[] dataToSend = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt16(fs.Length)); //Convert image to byte[]

        int i = 0;
        while (true) // this while for keeping the server "listening"
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a UDP client..."); // display stuff
            IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0); // prepare
            dataReceived = serverSocket.Receive(ref sender); // receive packet
            string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceived, 0, dataReceived.Length); // get string from packet
            Console.WriteLine("Response from " + sender.Address); // display stuff
            Console.WriteLine("Message " + i++ + ": " + stringData + "\n"); // display client's string

            // Here I am sending back
            serverSocket.Send(dataToSend, 8, sender);
        }
    }
}
```

**Java Client:** On button click this function gets called to send-receive-display

```
    public void SendUdpMsg(final String msg)
{
    Thread networkThread = new Thread() {

        // No local Host 127.0.0.1 in Android
        String host = "192.168.200.3"; // Server's IP
        int port = 15000;
        DatagramSocket dsocket = null;

        public void run() {
            try {
                // Get the Internet address of the specified host
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

                // wrap a packet
                DatagramPacket packetToSend = new DatagramPacket(
                        msg.getBytes(),
                        msg.length(),
                        address, port);

                // Create a datagram socket, send the packet through it.
                dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
                dsocket.send(packetToSend);

                // Here, I am receiving the response
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // prepare
                DatagramPacket packetReceived = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length); // prepare
                dsocket.receive(packetReceived); // receive packet
                byte[] buff = packetReceived.getData(); // convert packet to byte[]
                final Bitmap ReceivedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buff, 0, buff.length); // convert byte[] to image

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // this is executed on the main (UI) thread
                        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(ReceivedImage);
                    }
                });
                dsocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//catch
        }//run
    };// Networkthread
    networkThread.start();//networkThread.start()
}
```

Comment: UDP is not designed for bulk transfers of data that needs to stay in order and arrive intact. UDP packets sent in some order are not guaranteed to arrive in that order, or even arrive at all (for example if you send packets A,B,C,D,E you may get A,B,D,E,C or even A,E,C,D). Your string fit into one packet, but for the image, a single lost packet can spell disaster. Use TCP instead (using a normal Socket instead of a DatagramSocket).

Comment: @hexafraction I think I am aware of this but here I am testing with a 900 bytes image. Which should fit in my byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] no? However, my result is a null and not misordered or less than

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isn't much of an answer, but since I can't comments yolo

You should use TCP, it is so much better. Using UDP, I even loose data when it is 400 bytes.

It might be

```
serverSocket.Send(dataToSend, 8, sender);
```

Change it to

```
serverSocket.Send(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length, sender);
```

Also, try first sending the length of the image (dataToSend.Length) to the client, then have the client use the length you sent it to create a byte array. Kind like

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[recievedLengthOfImage]
```

Comment: That's what I've been told, TCP. I am really a noob student trying to achieve big thing which is why I am excited and motivated. Would you like to share your goal and how did you achieve it? Maybe part of the code? Anything to help me learn or move forward. And thanks for passing by, you helped anyway. Maybe now you can comment :)

Comment: Actually, this worked. I received the image without sending the Image length. Just wanted to tell you good job for catching it. However, on a new click I don't receive a new image. Do you know why?